# Parameter Passing an Array of Type in Delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi, class, types

I'm trying to pass an array out of a class into my main program in Delphi. I'm having a bit of trouble with the data types and an hour scouring the web has found nothing to help me. It sounds a bit strange, but the more complex the answer the better (it's for a college project).

I have a class connected to SQL which reads an SQL Query into an array of a record Type declarations (sorry if it's a bit messy at the moment) :

```
Type TScout = Record
SNum, FName, SName, Gender, Address, HomeNum, MobNum,
SEmail, STel, Hikes, Nights, Med, Diet : String;
DoB, DoJ : String;
End;

Type TScoutArray = Array of TScout;

Type TScoutSQL = Class
Public
  Procedure InitSQL;
  Procedure GetRecords;
  Function SendRecords : TScoutArray;
Private
  ScoutsArray : TScoutArray;
  ScoutConnection : TSQLConnection;
  ScoutQuery : TSQLQuery;
End;
```

So the whole "Function SendRecords : TScoutArray;" isn't working, as on the other side I have the same 2 types (TScout and TScoutArray) declared exactly the same, I call the function:

```
  ScoutArray := ScoutSQL.SendRecords;
```

And I get:

```
[Error] MembersUnit.pas(51): Incompatible types
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: _Record type declaration_ means a record, right? So, you read the data from a DBMS, store it in a record and try to pass a dynamic array of records around. You should also provide more code, like the type of ScoutArray. that is because `TScoutArray` and `array of TScout` are different types in Pascal/Delphi.

Comment: I made TScoutArray because I read you can't just pass an array out of a class, you have to make your own data type, but it still didn't work, so I asked here

Comment: if you found your answer you should mark it as accepted or supply more details if we haven't understood.

Comment: @David Heffernan Apologies for that. Now marked the answer. Thanks for answering swiftly and in a way I could easily understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that your problem is that you are declaring these types twice in separate units. Doing so results in distinct, incompatible types.

What you need to do is to:

- Declare the types, in the interface section, of one unit only (unit A, say).
- In another unit (unit B, say) that wants to use these types you add unit `A` to the `uses` clause.

Comment: or add the type declaration into the interface section of a third unit C, and include C in both A and Bs USES clauses.

Answer (score 2):

## Wrong way

```
var
  badArray: array of TScout;
begin
  badArray := ScoutSQL.SendRecords;
```

This won't work. `array of TScout` and `TScoutArray`, the latter being what SendRecords returns, are different types in Delphi/Pascal.

## Right way

```
var
  niceArray: TScoutArray;
begin
  niceArray := ScoutSQL.SendRecords;
```